# How to collect nested json keys to a linear list

Tags: python, json, nested, key

I'm working with large nested json and need collect all Json keys to list ,
i.e:

for json:

```
{"taxIncludedAmount":{},"impactingPriceParameter":[{}],"extensions":{"additionalProp1":{}}}}
```

I'd like to collect the key to a list,
and add the brackets so i know the type of the key.
so for above json i'd like to get(include the right order):

```
eventType
event{}.dataStrategy
event{}.error{}.code
event{}.error{}.characteristics[].name
```

I manage to get all keys using some code example found,
but having trouble find a way to add the brackets {} for dic and [] for list.

code:

```
         
def get_keys(d, curr_key=[]):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from get_keys(v, curr_key + [k])
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                yield from get_keys(i, curr_key + [k])
        else:
            yield '.'.join(curr_key + [k])
    

   
    
def main():
  array_json_keys = [*get_keys(json_data)]
```

output:

```
event.dataStrategy
event.error.characteristics.name
event.error.code
eventType
```

this is "almost there ,I need to add  the brackets ({} for dic ,[] for array)
in addition i'd like to get it sorted so first level object will be display first.

Update:

Thanks for @blhsing - it solve the brackets ,
from some reason it skipping empty keys in example

```
 "impactingPriceParameter": [
    {}
  ]

or 
  "extensions": {
    "additionalProp1": {}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply concatenate `'{}'` or `'[]'` to the key `k` depending on the data type of the value `v`:

```
def get_keys(d, curr_key=[]):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from get_keys(v, curr_key + [k + '{}'])
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                yield from get_keys(i, curr_key + [k + '[]'])
        else:
            yield '.'.join(curr_key + [k])
```

Comment: thanks a lot  , that nail it:)

for the sorting part , is there a way to sort the output so highest level key will display first?

Comment: You're welcome. To yield the highest level keys first you should use breadth-first-search (with a queue-based implementation) rather than depth-first-search (with recursion). Give it a try first and ask a new question if you're stuck.

Comment: If you want an easy (but less efficient) way to sort the list after the DFS, you can simply sort the list by the number of dots in each string.

Comment: to use bfs means that i first need to sort the dict keys and then call to the get_keys function ?